# position: sticky issue - element appears off-placed

Tags: css

the sticky positioning support in CSS is very nice, but with glitches!
I am using `position: sticky` on a two-column layout. I have a `select` dropdown in the section that is set to be sticky, when page is scrolled, the `select` in the sticky-positioned div renders way off its place, outside the div, where it would've appeared originally without any scrolling. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

when I click anywhere to close the dropdown, and then open it again, it renders fine in the correct place. This is happening on Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh5gq4z0/) with the issue replicated. Before opening the dropdown, scroll down a bit, and then click on the select.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Can you provide a live example?

Comment: just added a jsfiddle live example.

Comment: @mavili I can't reproduce the error in you fiddle.

Comment: @SergChernata What browser (with version) are you using? I've confirmed the bug in Chrome 59.

Comment: @jhpratt Same exact browser.

Comment: @SergChernata OS? I'm on Debian-based Linux. `<select>` elements are rendered by the OS, so it may be an issue with interop.

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a third party site which can change or disappear helping no one in the future. I would have thought you would know that: [mcve]

Comment: @jhpratt Nvm, I think the fiddle has changed. I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: Another reason to close this. There is no markup at all anywhere now that shows the problem.

Comment: @Rob I'm surprised you have over 10k reputation on SO and you're complaining about providing jsfiddle as a "third party site which can change or disappear". OK it's a third party site but it's such a popular and standard way of providing markup that people use it all the time. Risk of it going away? Well I guess SO itself may go away in the future!

Comment: Also, the fiddle never changed, i posted the first version and I haven't updated it.

Comment: Read the Help Center and my link if you want answers to why SO, not just me, **requires** you to post your markup here. In a nutshell, there is no guarantee your fiddle will not turn into a dead link sometime in the future and leave anyone looking for answers hanging and your question useless. In addition, code and comments in your fiddle is not searchable from SO. There are other reasons but those are the posted rules you were asked to read when you signed up here.

Comment: I want to add one more thing. If SO went away one day, that won't have an impact on jsfiddle but, if jsfiddle went away, that would have an enormous impact on SO if questions and answers were allowed to rely on it. If it was just me "complaining", you wouldn't be one more vote away from having this question closed for that very reason.

Comment: I understand and agree with most of the point you've raised @Rob.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at your example, this appears to be an artifact of the OS rendering `<select>` elements and not the browser. I'd suggest filing a bug report for [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/), as those are the browsers you reported it in (I've confirmed it in Chrome 59 on Debian-based Linux).